# MyService (extends IntentService) is not living forever

Tags: java, android

Helloeveryone.
I'm trying to make a permanently on service in Android, which sends a notification to the user every XX minutes. 
If the frequency of notifications every 5 minutes - everything works fine.
But if you put notifications every 30 minutes - the service dies and does not send any more.
There is a timer inside the service, every minute it checks whether to send a notification or not. I know that this is not the best way, but otherwise many instances of the service started and each with its own timer.

**But main question is - how to make a service living forever? 
And yes, I made a startForeground(), and it does not help me.**

PS: maybe this will help - I noticed that when the service starts, the method is immediately called on theDestroy (), but I'm definitely not calling it anywhere.
(API 21)

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

private DBUtil dbUtil;
NotificationManager manager;
Timer myNotifyTimer;

public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    dbUtil = DBUtil.getInstance(this);
    manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    startForeground(1,ForegroundNot());

    NotificationTimer(intent,this);

}

private Notification ForegroundNot(){
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setTicker("startForeground") 
            .setContentTitle("startForeground")
            .setContentText("startForeground")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    Notification Not = builder.build();
    return Not;
}

private void NotificationTimer(final Intent intent,final Context context){

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "subengparser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    myNotifyTimer = new Timer();
    myNotifyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (sharedPref.contains("ServiceStop")) {
                if (!sharedPref.getBoolean("ServiceStop",false)){
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                    int retryTime=sharedPref.getInt("RetryTime",0);
                    long lastNotifPlus = sharedPref.getLong("lastNotif",0)+retryTime;
                    long current=System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (current<lastNotifPlus){
                        return;
                    }
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref_1 = context.getSharedPreferences(
                            "subengparser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    EngUnit engUnit=dbUtil.getRepeatWord();
                    if (engUnit.getId()!=0){
                        AndroidNotifications myNot = new AndroidNotifications();
                        myNot.Notification(context,engUnit);
                        sharedPref_1.edit().putLong("lastNotif", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply(); // работает
                    }else {
                        manager.cancelAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },0,60000); 
}
```

**************** In main activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainFragment=new MainFragment();

    fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.replace(R.id.frameCont,mainFragment);
    fTrans.commit();

     if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) { // its not help!
         startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
    ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm trying to make a permanently on service in Android, which sends a notification to the user every XX minutes" -- please do not do this. **Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user**. Sitting around watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user. "I noticed that when the service starts, the method is immediately called on theDestroy ()" -- of course. That is the normal flow of `IntentService`: call `onHandleIntent()`, then shut down.

Comment: Ok, but how and where should I count the time and create notifications? Is not this the job of the service?

Comment: Use `JobScheduler`, `AlarmManager`, or a wrapper around those (e.g., Evernote's `android-job`).